# ORACLE Stored procedure works on sql developer but not in php

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm confronted to a strange issue here, I try to use an oracle stored procedure which works fine on sqldeveloper and java, but not on php.

I'm executing the query this way :

```
//$rqt_date = "SELECT DECODE( 1, NULL, 1, 33, '1', 44 ) as test FROM DUAL";
$rqt_date = "SELECT DATEPARAM('23/06/2016') as date_1900 FROM DUAL";

$parsed = ociparse($db_link, $rqt_date);
oci_execute($parsed,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($parsed, OCI_BOTH)) != false)
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

I test using the commented `$rqt_date` (decode) : I get results

```
Array
(
    [0] => 44
    [TEST] => 44
)
```

But when I use `DATEPARAM` I get 0 as values instead of 42542 (number of days since 1900) :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [DATE_1900] => 0
)
```

What I get in sqldeveloper:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b40V.png]

I have no errors in the php logs.

**The info about my server :**
PHP Version 5.3.8
System  Windows NT BOWSER 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) i586

Comment: You cannot use procedures in an SQL statement; they need to be in a PL/SQL block. Are you sure this isn't a (stored) function rather than a procedure?

Comment: Please can you post the source code for the `DATEPARAM` function?

Comment: Can you try with to_date('23/06/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') instead of '23/06/2016'

Answer (score 0):

> But when I use DATEPARAM I get [...] number of days since 1900

The `DATEPARAM` function should be very simple:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dateparam (
  dt IN DATE
) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN dt - DATE '1900-01-01';
END;
/
```

Now, this takes a `DATE` datatype (not a string).

So in PHP (not my language, so please excuse any errors) you can pass the required value as a bind variable:

```
$rqt_date = "BEGIN :r := DATEPARAM( :dt ); END;";
$parsed = ociparse($db_link, $rqt_date);
oci_bind_by_name($parsed, ":dt", new DateTime( "2016-06-23" ) );
oci_bind_by_name($parsed, ":r", $r, 40 );
oci_execute($parsed,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
print "$r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

Here is the code of the function (it's not a procedure, you're right)

```
create or replace function DateParam(strDate in varchar) return number DETERMINISTIC is
Result number := 0;
begin
If  Length (strDate) >=4 Then
    Result :=  to_date( strDate ) - to_date('01/01/1900');
End If;
return(Result);
exception
when others then
    return (0);
end DateParam;
```

It really looks like theone your wrote.

I tried with to_date('23/06/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') instead of '23/06/2016', it's still the same => 0

BUUUUUT

With the function you wrote it's working !

So we changed

```
to_date( strDate ) - to_date('01/01/1900');
```

from ours to

```
to_date( strDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy' ) - to_date('01/01/1900','dd/MM/yyyy');
```

And now it's working fine.

I don't understand why it was not working in php (all the modifications we made are in the function itself, so if it works in sqldeveloper, it should works everywhere ?)...

Thank you very much both of you !